# Presentation plugabble architecture MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, mef, mvccontrib

Building large web applications in one massive ASP.NET MVC project is not easy to manage, especially with multiple developers, as you know Controllers, Models, and business logic can all be put into separate packages.

but what I want is a little different than deployment, suppose several developers are working on a ASP.Net MVC project in **presentation layer** so what I want is that each developer can be able to work in her/his zone and at the end give me a package which is contains controller,model,views and UI staff such as CSS,JS,pics and etc...) then I patch it into the main project without any manipulate main project, so from what I have googled there are some plug-gable architecture to do this
but as you know each of them have it's pros and cons but I am hesitant to choose better,
there are some of them listed below:

1- MvcContrib

2- MEFContrib

3- Microsoft Unity

1- I think in Unity dependency injection there is a problem, after building package we should define all interface in main project(I think `UnityContainer`) so it is a problem because you must change the main project and rebuild it

2- In Mef and MVCContrib there are some other problem such as memory leak and they are embed all CSS and UI staff to a dll, so think a about if we want to change one of that css file then developer should rebuild all the package.

so what you think about the above problem or is there solution to make they easier to use or I am going wrong because I am newbie to use them.

which one is better according to their pros and cons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, but what you want to achieve is some sort of a version control to allow multiple groups of people working on the same project, where each group could branch their feature to work on and merge it back later... ?

Comment: No I don't want to achieve to sort of version control, I want something modular pluggable UI.

Comment: You can achieve this with Unity DI framework using Register by convention, where you don't have to explicitly register every type. Please take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507479(v=pandp.30).aspx

Comment: @Vinod.+1 So you tell that Unity DI can be the best choice?

Comment: Register by convention is supported by most of the DI frameworks such as Unity, Autofaq, Ninject and others. What you want to achieve is possible using any of these DI frameworks. Which DI framework you want to choose depends on what your team is already familiar with. They all have similar features with different syntax and few edge case differences. As long as you centralize DI container usage and registrations, you can always switch the DI framework without altering the actual application behavior.